# Button change to input email onclick jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I would like to ask about changing a button to email input field after click. The div of the button is:

html

```
<button class="read-more-button email-button" id="news-button" onClick="addInputField()">Enter your email</button>
```

The function

```
function addInputField(){
    var element = document.createElement("input");
    element.setAttribute("type", "email");
    element.setAttribute("value", "");
    element.setAttribute("name", "Email");
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    document.getElementById("news-button").innerHTML = element.value; 
 }
```

But I get the empty value from the attribute `element.setAttribute("value", "");`

How can I change the button into email input field after it's clicked and get the value of the field?

Comment: You the the element value to "" so of course you then get "" when you get the value.

Comment: What I'm asking is how to change that. Should I leave value empty?

Comment: You need to explain what you are trying to do.  The code above doesn't really make sense.  Edit the question to clearly explain the steps you are trying to achieve - don't just say something like "I don't want blank value", or you won't get any help.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you do it with [replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) function

```js
$('#news-button').click(function(){
      $(this).replaceWith( "<input id='emailAddress' type='email'>" );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="read-more-button email-button" id="news-button">Enter your email</button>
```

Comment: thank but it doesn't work on my project though, to be more specifc it will not turn the cursor into text to write.